# How to use var variable value to show div in html

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, ejs

I have defined the variable (city) in ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var city = getQueryStringValue("region")
  console.log("city::",city);
}
```

Now I want to get the value of city in html div and apply the condition to show the div. I'm using ejs file.
I am getting value of city in console.

```
<% if(city!=undefined && city!=''){ %>
<p>
    <b>
    <span id="city"></span>, 
    <span id="country"></span>
    </b>
</p>
<p class="jp-font-12">
    <span class="jp-m-r-10"> 
        <span id="checkin" style="display: none;"></span> 
        <span id="checkout" style="display: none;"> </span> 
        <span id="checkinFrm"></span> - <span id="checkoutTo"> </span> 
    </span>
    <span id="roompickers"></span>
</p>
<% } else { %>
<p></p>
<% } %>
```

My intention is to show the html content only when city value is not undefined or blank. How to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually **you just can pass variables to your view from your controller on the server-side node, before rendering DOM**, so if you intend to pass variables during the render, as far as I know, you can't do this. **The best way to do it is to create your whole element in your JS and then append it to your HTML**.

So let's say we have an HTML element like this:

```html
<div id="dom"></div>
```

Then we want to append our element to it whenever `city` exists.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var city = getQueryStringValue("region");
  if (city != undefined && city != "") { // It's better to replace your condition with if(city)
    var element = `<p><b><span id="city"></span>, <span id="country"></span></b></p><p class="jp-font-12"><span class="jp-m-r-10"><span id="checkin" style="display: none;"></span> <span id="checkout" style="display: none;"> </span><span id="checkinFrm"></span> - <span id="checkoutTo"></span></span><span id="roompickers"></span></p>`;
    $("#dom").append(element);
  }
});
```

Comment: It appending the html element but data doesn't.

Comment: Sure. actually in the <div id="dom"></div> , the html element which we are appending in the $(document).ready(function() {} is appending properly. but the value of city doesn't coming its blank actually.

Comment: @LalitDubey If you want to put any variable within your HTML you can do this by [`${city}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). For example if you want to put the city value within you `span` with `id="city"`, it will be like this: `<span id="city">${city}</span>`. Just make sure you are using template literals (``).

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is to show some html if city variable is present. You cant use client-side JS on your pre-rendered DOM, so if you want to use EJS on your client-side, you need to add this script tag into your html head tag:

```html
<script src="ejs.js"></script>
```

And then use ejs object to parse some html, just like this:

```js
let ejscode = 'your-ejs-code';
let completeCode = ejs.render(ejscode, {city: city});
$('#container').append(completeCode);
```

If city is defined and not null the code will appear.